# Audio in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add audio as an input to  below command, How can I achieve it

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -i test.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1422:800[scale1],[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0],[0:v][rotate0]overlay=258.04:107.71[mediaoverlayout0],color=black@0:451x137[c1],[c1]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile='/Windows/fonts/Peddana-Regular.ttf':text='ADITYA':fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.91,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext1],[mediaoverlayout0][rottext1]overlay=x=544.63:y=263.076:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p op.mp4
```

Comment: What audio? Audio from a file or...?

Comment: yes external audio

Comment: Try editing your question to state exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Detail still lacking, but try adding `-i audio.mp3` as the third input.

Comment: another question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140371/video-with-music-taking-long-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `test.mp4` has no audio and you want audio from `audio.mp3`:

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -i test.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1422:800[scale1],[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0],[0:v][rotate0]overlay=258.04:107.71[mediaoverlayout0],color=black@0:451x137[c1],[c1]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile='/Windows/fonts/Peddana-Regular.ttf':text='ADITYA':fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.91,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext1],[mediaoverlayout0][rottext1]overlay=x=544.63:y=263.076:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p op.mp4
```

If `test.mp4` has audio, but you only want audio from `audio.mp3`:

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -i test.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1422:800[scale1],[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0],[0:v][rotate0]overlay=258.04:107.71[mediaoverlayout0],color=black@0:451x137[c1],[c1]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile='/Windows/fonts/Peddana-Regular.ttf':text='ADITYA':fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.91,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext1],[mediaoverlayout0][rottext1]overlay=x=544.63:y=263.076:shortest=1" -map 2:a -pix_fmt yuv420p op.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you Ilogan, But how to limit time with respect to the input video duration

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Should be asked as a new question. Answer depends on the input durations of `test.mp4` and `audio.mp3`.