# Video with music taking long time

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I am rendering video with filters and adding audio at the end. But while running it is taking a long time and rendering continuously. Can anyone help me where I am wrong? below is the command

```
 ffmpeg -i test.png -i test.mp4 -i test.mp3  -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1422:800[scale1],[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0],[0:v][rotate0]overlay=258.04:107.71[mediaoverlayout0],color=black@0:451x137[c1],[c1]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile='/Windows/fonts/Peddana-Regular.ttf':text='ADITYA':fontsize=121.199:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.91,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext1],[mediaoverlayout0][rottext1]overlay=x=544.63:y=263.076[out]" -vcodec libx264 -map "[out]" -map 2:a -preset veryfast -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p op.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `-shortest` output option because `color=black@0:451x137` does not have an end time and therefore encodes indefinitely.

I'm guessing you're trying to make a transparent box behind the text. If that's what you are trying to do then use the various `box` options in drawtext instead.

Also, you are using the rotate filter with a value of 0. You could just omit them since they are doing nothing.